# How to get a cell value's integer character only from worksheet formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Is there a worksheet formula that will return the cell value's integer character only? For example, the cell value is "500+", I want to return the value "500". I know there are functions that will remove the "+" sign but I was wondering if there is a worksheet formula that will do that as well?

I've tried

```
=if(a1, "...+", value, 0) ?
```

Comment: " I know there are functions ... if there is a worksheet formula " - those are synonyms, please specify what you've already tried and why that isn't fine for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that extra character is always `+`, then use

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+","")`

Comment: Yep, this works if the cell is `500+` like the example. Not for anything more complicated though, which isn't specified in the question. +1